# How do I add a download button for a preview page in react

Tags: reactjs

I am confused on how to add a button to a preview form page in react, such that a user can download the page for reference.

```
function PreviewMain({
  mdaEnroll,
  passport,
  bloodGroup,
  nokPhone,
  selectedFacility,
  myDate,
  enrollmentId,
}) {
  return (
    <div >
    

      <img
        src={URL.createObjectURL(passport)}
        alt={"passport"}
        width={200}
        height={200}
       
      />
      <table >
        <thead></thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Name: </td>
            <td >
              {mdaEnroll?.name}
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Blood Group: </td>
            <td>
              {bloodGroup}
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Next of Kin contact: </td>
            <td >
              {nokPhone}
            </td>
          </tr>
          
         
          <tr>
            <td>Enrollment Id: </td>
            <td>
              
              {enrollmentId}
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <h3>
        <i>please print this page for reference</i>
      </h3>

   <button >Download</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default PreviewMain;
```

I'm struggling to find similar implementation. The user onClick the download button should be able to get the table in pdf format. i'll appreciate any help

Comment: If I understand correctly, you first need to find a way to convert your HTML into PDF and then download that. I don't think it's a simple answer because I assume it would include couple of packages and canvas API to do that. But maybe somebody else can help and provide a simpler solution. Good luck.

Comment: You can use `window.print()` API to print the current page in `pdf` format. Combined with `onClick`,  you can print it. Reference - [window.print API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/print)

Comment: Can you try the `jsPDF` package? It will work as you espect.